# In Coded UI, how to identify and click only the part of HTML link

Tags: c#

The application that I have been testing allows reviewing the images for the items that customer selected earlier. To do this, there is a list of HTML links provided at the bottom of the web page. 
For instance, if customer picked the alcohol drinks, the HTML links may look like:

*Vodka – Alcohol Drinks*

*Beer – Alcohol Drinks*

*Gin – Alcohol Drinks*

Etc.

When I create my Coded UI script, it is an easy task to identify this whole text, e.g.  “*Vodka – Alcohol Drinks*” as the InnerText  for Htmlhyperlink and have my script clicking on it.

However, I can not predict which drink was selected earlier, e.g. vodka, beer or gin, and the one variant of InnerText (“*Vodka – Alcohol Drinks*” in my example) can not match all possible sorts of drinks' names.  Because of this, the Coded UI script fails mostly (unless if vodka was selected).

As such, it would be logical to cut off the name of drinks from the HTML links and let my Coded UI script to find and click only words “Alcohol Drinks” which remains the same.  And this is where I stuck.

I would appreciate for any idea on how to do this task.

This is the only piece that work for one match only.

```
HtmlHyperlink alcoholDrinksLink = new HtmlHyperlink(PreSelectedPage);     
alcoholDrinksLink.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Hyperlink");        
alcoholDrinksLink.SearchProperties.Add("InnerText", "Vodka - Alcohol Drinks");
Mouse.Click(alcoholDrinksLink);
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have written so far.

Comment: This is the only piece that work for one match only.
`HtmlHyperlink alcoholDrinksLink = new HtmlHyperlink (PreSelectedPage);
            alcoholDrinksLink.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Hyperlink");
            alcoholDrinksLink.SearchProperties.Add("InnerText", "Vodka - Alcohol Drinks");
            Mouse.Click(alcoholDrinksLink);`

Answer (score 0):

After working with our developer, we came up to the following solution that works:

HtmlTable hyperlinksBox = new HtmlTable(reviewPurchaseHtmlDocument); //Identify a container (or box) with all the hyperlinks

hyperlinksBox.SearchProperties.Add("Id", "DEApplication:content:vc:dt1"); //add the search properties to find your table

HtmlControl hyperlink = new HtmlControl(hyperlinksBox); //Identify each single hyperlink which resides in the container
           hyperlink.SearchProperties.Add("TagName", "A");
           UITestControlCollection drinksHyperlinks = hyperlink.FindMatchingControls();

```
       foreach (var link in drinksHyperlinks)
       {

           Mouse.Click(link); //click the link 
           Playback.Wait(5000); //and review it for 5 seconds
       }
```